# What are the top tips for maintaining a CMS like Umbraco?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

As a digital producer working with a developer on a bespoke Umbraco project I understand that the only way to ensure that Umbraco stays up to date is to write tests for any code added to the repository and to use a continuous integration server. How can the Umbraco be kept up to date while adding our own bespoke modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every project that has a "large" code base could potentially benefit from continuous integration and automated testing. CMS based projects could certainly benefit from automated UI testing, as well as unit testing if you are adding custom functionality to the back- and front-end.

Umbraco based projects, basically asp.net projects, can benefit from this approach too.

**Why do you need automated testing?**
(assuming a large code base, not just 1 simple marketing site)
Because manual testing is time consuming and can only be done by a one person or a team of testers. If you have UI tests, for example in Selenium, every developer could run these tests on their local installation to test before they commit to the source control server. Non-developers can also run these tests too, for example against the staging server. Selenium (or any other package) tests can be run before you deploy, and/or after you deploy.

Doing all these tests manually will take quite some of your time.
Maintaining these test will also take a bit more time, 
but far less then you would do them manually each and every time you deploy.

For Umbraco you can use the following tools:

- Unit testing in Visual Studio: has templates for Unit testing projects which you can use to write unit tests to test your custom code.
- Unit testing Umbraco: check the latest code, as they have some code that can help you with that. Some additional information: http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2010-06-29-unit-testing-with-umbraco.html
- Selenium: can run against your sites, and perform all kinds of UI testing such as verifying forms, javascript functionality.
- Qunit: if you need javascript unit tests. (i haven't used this, but we are looking into a solution to test our javascripts).

**Why continuous integration?**
CI can help you catch bugs early as the build will run every night, or even every time some one commits new code to source control. Especially if you are working in a team, CI can be quite helpful in avoiding code clashes. Combining CI, with the automated UI tests is even better. Every night, the project gets to be build on a server, the UI tests run, and in the morning you, as the producer, can get the report, whether everything passed, the build worked, etc...

- Cuisecontrol.Net and NANT
  Cruisecontrol and Nant are both open-source tools and can be installed on most Windows servers.
  These tools can pull the code from svn (or other source control servers) and rebuild the project. Nant can then copy the files, create IIS sites, update appPools, etc.. to create a fresh website.

This approach requires additional infrastructure (ci server, svn server, additional installations etc...) , and might be a bit bulky if you are just working on a smaller site.

I do use Umbraco within this context: CI + selenium tests on an eCommerce project that builds around 50 Umbraco sites every night, and runs some basic selenium tests. Every morning the sites are fresh and based on the latest code.